# Mais opções de formatação

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado, formatação

Seria muito interessante se tivéssemos mais opções de formatação como alinhamento, tabulações, margens, texto justificado, centralizado, etc., um mini Open Office. Além de ficar muito mais organizado, as publicações ficariam mais bonitas aos olhos.

Uma variedade mínima de fontes também não seria ruim.

Comment: Ênfase não em estilo, mas no posicionamento.

Answer (score 9):

Isso lembra os velhos fóruns da internet, onde a liberdade de formatação é total, justificação pra um lado, pra outro, fontes diferentes, muitas cores... o resultado final não fica exatamente de fácil leitura.

Fui dar uma (re)conferida no [Discourse](http://try.discourse.org/), que é o novo projeto de um dos fundadores do SO, onde aplica muito do que aprendeu aqui para modernizar em *vários* aspectos essa plataforma social tão antiga e popular que é o fórum na web:

<kbd>[image: discourse edit box]</kbd>

**Zero.** Zip. Niente. Markdown básicão e acabou. Separando as idéias em parágrafos claros, usando ênfase com cuidado, uma imagem aqui, uma lista de links ali, e pronto. O objetivo que é comunicar idéias e transmitir conhecimentos não fica embaralhado no meio da cacofonia estética de uma multidão querendo formatar seu post o mais destacadamente possível.

E essa simplificação não saiu do nada, são vários anos de estudo, observação direta, análise estatística e sociológica; [aqui uma apresentação](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEc6Eyogb9Y) um pouco comprida (e em inglês) do Jeff Atwood mas que explica em detalhes o histórico do Stack Overflow e do Discourse.

<sup>*Depoimento pessoal: depois do Markdown minha vida mudou completamente e depois desta [**ferramenta aqui**](https://stackedit.io/editor#), ainda mais.*</sup>

Comment: Relacionado: [*Allowing users to justify text in questions/answers*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231857/185667)